# Read Scanner input and load client side page with new information

Tags: angular, barcode-scanner, event-listener, pdf417

My requirement is to read scanner input data from a serial port and take certain action on client side web page based on the data read. Each client machine will have a separate scanner attached to the client machine but as multiple devices like desktop, tablet, phone would need to take action using the scanner input we need separation of concerns and not have hard binding.

One of the solution proposed is to use a generic service to read scanner input and put the input data on a server side Jason. UI will implement a listener to monitor any changes in server side Jason object or document and take action to reload the web page based on certain criteria.

I want to know how to implement a listener to monitor changes in serverside jason and take action to load the new data based on this event using Angular 4.